# Jquery AJAX form POST submit issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have the following AJAX code, on success, I would like to redirect using post method so I have a dummy form (id="form-post-change-tab") and redirecting to ./landing via post.

Problem is this function immediately submits the form $(#form-post-change-tab).submit(); instead of calling the AJAX request and redirecting on success method.

Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
    $("#form-CreateNewTab").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/create-tab",
            data: $('#form-CreateNewTab').serialize(),

            success: function(msg){
                //alert(msg);
                $('#tabID').val(msg);
                $(#form-post-change-tab).submit();
            },

            error: function(){
                alert("newtab failure");
            }

        });
    });
});




<form id="form-post-change-tab" action="./landing" method="post">
    <input id="tabID" type="hidden" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your form id does not have quotes around it !

```
$(#form-post-change-tab).submit()
```

needs quotes

```
$('#form-post-change-tab').submit()
```

Comment: "#form-CreateNewTab" is actually a different form (modal bootstrap dialog form) when I submit it call "#form-CreateNewTab" function

Comment: Dang!!! You nailed it....I didnt have quotes in $(#form-post-change-tab).submit()...Thank you!